# How to scrape a new popup using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape information from a popup box that appears after I click a button. The yellow "Contact" button that opens a new window revealing a hidden phone number that needs to be scraped. I tried clicking on that button and then scraping the text but I was unable to do so.

This is the link to the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2qtc.png)

This is the link to the website :
https://www.carlist.my/used-cars-for-sale/mazda/malaysia#1004411695

The error that I was originally getting after getting the very first phone number was

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException:

This error was resolved by closing the popup window before trying to click the next "Contact" button.
Here is my revised code:

```
button = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('listing__ctr.btn.btn--large.btn--primary.one-whole.btn--large.js-contact-seller.js-show-top.js-contact-seller--jump-phone')

    for j in button:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", j)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", j)
        pop_up = driver.find_element_by_class_name('modal.js-modal-dealer.modal--dealer.modal--dealer-ctr')
        time.sleep(5)

        try:
            dealer_name = pop_up.find_element_by_class_name('listing__seller-name.js-chat-profile-fullname.c-seller-name.u-text-5.u-margin-bottom-none').text
            dealer.append(dealer_name)
            print(dealer)

            try:
                phone = pop_up.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.one-whole.u-flex__fill').text
                dealer_phoneNo.append(phone)
                print(dealer_phoneNo)
                driver.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.modal__destroy.b-close.weight--light.js-modal-destroy').click()
                time.sleep(3)
                whole = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
                whole.send_keys(Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN)
            except:
                dealer.append('Null')
                dealer_phoneNo.append('Null')
                whole = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
                whole.send_keys(Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN)
        except:
            pass
```

This revised code now does scrape the phone number and the dealer name properly. I have 2 new issues:

1. It does it twice for each "Contact" button
   and
2. After it scrolls down to scrape other buttons, one of the pop-up windows does not display the phone number. I thought is was an exception, but the "try..catch" is not catching it.

Currently I have no idea how should I move forward.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Please share the code and the error that you are facing.

Comment: Whats the error you are getting?

Comment: close the popup box before trying to click on the next contact button

Comment: and do you get the error after it prints the first phone number or before?

Comment: @JeremyKahan after it prints the1st phone number

Comment: @JeremyKahan I tried closing the pop up before it tries to click on the next contact but it still gives the same error

Comment: did you wait to make sure it was gone? So driver.getWindowHandles().size();is what is was before you clicked on the contact button? Also, it may help to store the handle of the parent window and explicitly switchTo it before clicking on another contact button.

Comment: @JeremyKahan i have updated the code please let me know what more changes are required

Comment: I updated my answer below. I think you may want to take the closing of the popup box and put it in a "finally" so it happens even if dealer or phone is missing, Also, I have edited the question to clarify so it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in comments, it was important to close the window beofre going on to the next thing.
The scrollintoview associated with click for things beyond the first was not working. At least in firefox, when I used jsExecute of a click, it did not mind that you could not see what it was clicking on. But it was a bit ugly to watch, so I scrolled manually with down arrows. Here is the result. Note some of the things have 2 phone numbers, which you might want to handle.

Sorry for the red herrings about window handles. It turned out the popup was not really separate.

```
for j in phone:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", j)
    time.sleep(3)
    pop_up = driver.find_element_by_class_name('modal.js-modal-dealer.modal--dealer.modal--dealer-ctr')
    phone = pop_up.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.one-whole.u-flex__fill').text
    print(phone)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.modal__destroy.b-close.weight--light.js-modal-destroy').click()
    time.sleep(3)
    whole = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    whole.send_keys(Keys.DOWN+Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN + Keys.DOWN)
```

**Update**: As you noted, the above was clicking on each contact twice. That is a specific feature of that page, for which your locator matched each Contact button twice. So I went with it and alternated. Meanwhile, another issue I had was that there was a contact without a phone number, which was causing an error (I see you added try catch to handle that) . That is why I added a check that there were any matches before trying to get text from it. Finally, I got rid of the down arrows, which were strange and imprecise and went with executing a scroll into view before executing click. This was scrolling them into view for me, and I see you did so too.

So here is what I ended up with. You can adapt your above revised code to do the same alternating.

```
i = 0
for j in button:
    i = i + 1
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        continue
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", j)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", j)
    time.sleep(5)
    pop_up = driver.find_element_by_class_name('modal.js-modal-dealer.modal--dealer.modal--dealer-ctr')
    phones = pop_up.find_elements_by_class_name('flexbox__item.one-whole.u-flex__fill')
    if len(phones) > 0:
        phone = pop_up.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.one-whole.u-flex__fill').text
        print(phone)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.modal__destroy.b-close.weight--light.js-modal-destroy').click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

**I think final update:**
You were right that try..except would catch the error if phone number did not appear. You just needed to recover that by closing the popup window anyway. Here is what that approach could look like (I took out a few things that in my testing I had not declared). I also got rid of the down arrows and kept the alternating as explained above.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('listing__ctr.btn.btn--large.btn--primary.one-whole.btn--large.js-contact-seller.js-show-top.js-contact-seller--jump-phone')
i = 0
for button in buttons:
    i = i + 1
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        continue
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", button)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
    time.sleep(3)
    pop_up = driver.find_element_by_class_name('modal.js-modal-dealer.modal--dealer.modal--dealer-ctr')
    #dealer name never missing, so simplified
    dealer_name = pop_up.find_element_by_class_name('listing__seller-name.js-chat-profile-fullname.c-seller-name.u-text-5.u-margin-bottom-none').text
    print(dealer_name)
    try:
        phone = pop_up.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.one-whole.u-flex__fill').text
        print(phone)
    except:
        print("missing phone")
    finally:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('flexbox__item.modal__destroy.b-close.weight--light.js-modal-destroy').click()
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: It clicks on the same contact button twice & as it further goes down onto other buttons the pop-up window does not displays the phone number